# What is difference between os.getuid() and os.geteuid()?

Tags: python, uid

The documentation for `os.getuid()` says:

> Return the current process’s user id.

And of `os.geteuid()` says:

> Return the current process’s effective user id.

So what is the difference between **user id** and **effective user id**?

For me both works same *(on both 2.x and 3.x)*. I am using it to check if script is being run as root.

Comment: They are not the same in setuid programs (and they might be different for any program running as root and calling seteuid explicitly). This means they *are* the same when your script starts up.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To understand how `os.getuid` and `os.geteuid` differ, you need to understand that they're are not Python specific functions (other than the `os` module prefix). Those functions are wrapping the `getuid` and `geteuid` system calls that are provided by essentially all Unix-like operating systems.

So, rather than looking at Python docs (which are not likely to give a lot of details), you should look at the docs for your operating system. [Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/geteuid.2.html) is the relevant documentation for Linux, for example. Wikipedia also has a good [article on Unix User IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier).

The difference between the regular UID and the Effective UID is that only the EUID is checked when you do something that requires special access (such as reading or writing a file, or making certain system calls). The UID indicates the actual user who is performing the action, but it is (usually) not considered when examining permissions. In normal programs they will be the same. Some programs change their EUID to add or subtract from the actions they are allowed to take. A smaller number also change their UID, to effectively "become" another user.

Here's an example a program that changes its EUID: The `passwd` program (which is used to change your password) must write to the system's password file, which is owned by the root user. Regular users can't write to that file, since if they could, they could change everyone else's password too. To resolve this, the `passwd` program has a bit set in its file permissions (known as the `setuid bit`) that indicates to the OS that it should be run with the EUID of the program's owner (e.g. `root`) even when it is launched by another user. The `passwd` program would then see its `UID` as the launching user, and its EUID as root. Writing to the system password file requires the EUID to be privileged. The UID is useful too, since `passwd` needs to know which user it's changing the password for.

There are a few other cases where the UID and EUID won't match, but they're not too common. For instance, a file server running as the super user might change its EUID to match a specific user who is requesting some file manipulations. Using the user's EUID allows the server to avoid accessing things that the user is not allowed to touch.

Comment: TL;DR: "*only the EUID is checked when you do something that requires special access [...]. The UID indicates the actual user who is performing the action, but it is (usually) not considered when examining permissions*" (You buried the answer a bit by putting it in the third paragraph)

Answer (score 7):

Function `os.getuid()` returns ID of a user who runs your program.  Function `os.geteuid()` of a user your program use permissions of.  In most cases this will be the same.  Well known case when these values will be different is when `setuid` bit is set for your program executable file, and user that runs your program is different from user that own program executable.  In this case `os.getuid()` will return ID of user who runs program, while `os.geteuid()` will return ID of user who own program executable.

Comment: Can you elaborate `os.geteuid()` part? And can you give example(s) to show that both are not same i.e. *x* can be achieved only with getuid and not geteuid, and *y* can only be achieved only with geteuid and not getuid?