# Encode a string in python 3.4

Tags: android, python-3.x, buffer, root

I am getting this error when I run this script in python 3.4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "qcdlcomm.py", line 23, in <module>
if not call('whoami')[0] == 'root':
File "qcdlcomm.py", line 20, in call
return  subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().strip().split("\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I think the answer is here [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface) but I don't know how to implement it.

[qcdlcomm.py](https://mega.nz/#!HsRBGDqJ!qFgezczBEoQfXhzaNWju8CSD057KUTUGqu3L4-7qBI4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

Answer (score 2):

[`bytes.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split) does not accept `str` (Unicode type in Python 3):

```
>>> b'abc'.split("\n")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

The error message is improved in Python 3.5:

```
>>> b"abc".split("\n")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

`"\n"` (`str` type) is a Unicode string (text) that is not `bytes`-like (binary data) in Python 3.

---

To get the output of `whoami` command as a Unicode string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

username = check_output(['whoami'], universal_newlines=True).rstrip("\n")
```

`universal_newlines` enables text mode. `check_output()` redirects child's stdout automatically and raises an exception on its nonzero exit status.

Note: `shell=True` is unnecessary here (you don't need the shell, to run `whoami`).

---

Unrelated: to find out whether you are `root` in Python, you could use [`geteuid()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14950378/4279):

```
import os

if os.geteuid() == 0:
   # I'm root (or equivalent e.g., `setuid`)
```

If you need to [find out what is the current user name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842059/4279):

```
import getpass

print('User name', getpass.getuser())
```

Beware: [don't use `getuser()` for access control purposes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python#comment650378_842096)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are treated differently in python3. Strings are not the same as bytes. What you get from calling `whoami` is a byte array. To fix the `call` function, simply decode the bytes into a string:

```
def call(cmd,hide_stderr=True):                                                 
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip().split("\n")
```

This is a similar issue as mentioned in [Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string).

Note that this is only a quick fix, but will work for your use case. Simply insert `.decode('utf-8')` into line 20 between `.read()` and `.strip()`.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't hardcode `utf-8` encoding. Pass `universal_newlines=True` or use `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will this work?   '`def call(cmd,hide_stderr=True):
 return subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip().split("\n")`

`#make sure we are root
if not call('whoami', universal_newlines=True)[0] == 'root':
 print ("run as root")
 sys.exit()`

Comment: No. The `call` function defined on line 19 does not have a `universal_newlines` argument. Simply replace the function definition on lines 19-20 with the version I gave you as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want to use text mode with Popen in Python 3 (and assuming that you use cPython implementation), you can pass either `encoding`, `error` or `universal_newlines` argument to Popen constructor. For example:

```
return subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout.read().strip().split("\n")
```

Thats because in cPython implementation of the `__init__` in `Popen` there is a following line:

```
text_mode = encoding or errors or universal_newlines
```

This is also what `check_output` in cPython internally does - it assures that `input` keyword argument (if present and `None`) is of appropriate type and passes the keyword arguments to `run` (which later calls `Popen`):

```
def check_output(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')

    if 'input' in kwargs and kwargs['input'] is None:
        # Explicitly passing input=None was previously equivalent to passing an
        # empty string. That is maintained here for backwards compatibility.
        kwargs['input'] = '' if kwargs.get('universal_newlines', False) else b''

    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
**kwargs).stdout
```

See more in [subprocess.py source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py).