# Volttron - refusing to run as root to prevent potential damage

Tags: python, git, error-handling, terminal, volttron

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a VM and am trying to run [Volttron](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron) using the standard install instructions, however I keep getting an error after the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev openssl libssl-dev libevent-dev git
git clone https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron
cd volttron
python bootstrap.py
```

My problem is with the last step `python bootstrap.py`. As soon as I get to this step, I get the error `bootstrap.py: error: refusing to run as root to prevent potential damage.` from my terminal window.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That comes from [this part of `bootstrap.py`](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/62c766650caf554621b6c94422ddf47f4485a799/bootstrap.py#L261-L268)  (and [this commit](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/commit/8800858ff0944d0da3ece65981b11024be8a5880))

```
# Refuse to run as root
if not getattr(os, 'getuid', lambda: -1)():
    sys.stderr.write('%s: error: refusing to run as root to prevent '
                     'potential damage.\n' % os.path.basename(argv[0]))
    sys.exit(77)
```

So check if you do have a [`os.getuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getuid) (current process’s real user id), because [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) mentions:

> If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise [`AttributeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError) is raised.

See "[What is difference between `os.getuid()` and `os.geteuid()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950419/6309)".
Maybe your terminal windows was launched as root. (check the output of `id -a`)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, because volttron didn't have permission to setup virtual env so I typed this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path_of_volttron_location
```